# Ethereum contracts are deployed to the main net but are not detected by metamask

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I used infura to deploy to kovan and ropsten and both were working fine. I deployed to the main net using truffle. But the Dapp that interacts with the smart contracts is not detected by metamask.

[image]

I get the following error in the console

```
Error: Incidents has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
    at Object.checkNetworkArtifactMatch (utils.js:261)
    at constructorMethods.js:61
    at u (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:274)
    at Generator.forEach.e.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:97)
    at r (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at s (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
sign-up.js:43 TypeError: s.createAccount is not a function
    at sign-up.js:38
    at u (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:274)
    at Generator.forEach.e.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:97)
    at n (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at s (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
```

I have two networks running on truffle. ropsten and the main net both for the same contracts. I tried

```
sudo truffle network --clean
```

so I only had the main net network, I thought having multiple networks running might have been messing it up. But both networks are still running after I run that command.

I then made a build of the react app and put that on a vps but it is the same result. Please help me . This is the last thing I need to do to finish my project but still can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: Can you provide a mainnet address for your contract?

Comment: 0x0af799745052f020bD8b3AEE87775029D1A9364a  this is the contract that I got the error message with above

Comment: The contract is indeed deployed on the mainnet. Such an error message indicates that you are using the wrong network (perhaps from MetaMask) or you are initializing with the wrong contract address.